# change value of an integer using parseInt

Tags: java, int, parseint

So I'm writing a method that is supposed to prompt the user to enter their pin number as a string, which is then converted to an int (or not depending on if it throws an exception), which I need to be assigned to the int pinNumber.

The problem I'm having is that the new object is assigned a pin number by the constructor when created, and this value isn't being changed when the below method is executed. What am I missing?

```
   public boolean canConvertToInteger()
   {
      boolean result = false;
      String pinAttempt;
      {
         pinAttempt = OUDialog.request("Enter your pin number");
         try
         {
            int pinNumber = Integer.parseInt(pinAttempt);
            return true;
         }
          catch (NumberFormatException anException)
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
```

EDIT: Changed pinAttempt to pinNumber (typo)

Comment: `pinAttempt` is a String, not an int

Comment: @mstbaum `parseInt` convert String to int.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard "which I need to be assigned to the *int* pinAttempt"

Comment: @mstbaum According to the code, I'm pretty sure this is a typo.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard you're probably right, but I didn't want to make assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this block

```
try
{
   int pinNumber = Integer.parseInt(pinAttempt);
   return true;
}
```

`pinNumber` will only have the value you expect in the scope of the try block.

I think you want to do

```
try
{
   this.pinNumber = Integer.parseInt(pinAttempt);
   return true;
}
```

instead.